# Generator of group, find the inverse, solve equation

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups

Given the prime number $p=101$

- Find a generator of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$. How many generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$ are there? Find $5$ generators.
- Find the inverse of $\overline{83}$ at the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$.
- Solve the equation $\overline{83} x=\overline{10}$ at the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$.
- We have that $\mathbb{Z}_{101}^{\star}=\{ 1,2, \dots, 100 \} $. So do we have to check if it holds that $1^{100}\equiv1 \mod{101}, 2^{100}\equiv 1 \mod{101}, 3^{100} \equiv 1 \mod{101}, \dots$ and if this holds for a number we know that it is a generator of the group? Or am I wrong?

  I found the following proposition:

  The number of generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$ is $\phi(p-1) \geq \frac{p}{\log{\log{p}}}$. Does this mean that we cannot find the exact number but there is only a lower bound?
- We want to find a $x \in \{1,2 , \dots, 100 \}$ such that $83 \cdot x \equiv 1 \mod{101}$, right? Is the only way to find such a $x$ to check all the products $83 \cdot 1, 83 \cdot 2, \dots$ till we find one that is equivalent to $1$ modulo $101$?

Comment: Of course we can find the exact number - $p$ is explicitly given, so in principle you could just try every number between $1$ and $p$ and check if it's a generator, thus counting the number of generators.

Answer (score 2):

It is a theorem that $a^{100} \equiv 1 \mod{101}$ will hold for every $a$ not divisible by 101.  Being a generator means that 100 is the least such exponent, so that $a^{i} \not\equiv 1\mod{101}$ for any $1 \le i< 100$.  As an example, 10 is not a generator because $10^2 \equiv -1 \mod{101}$ and thus $10^4 \equiv (-1)^2 = 1\mod{101}$.

To make it easier than checking by brute force that $a^{i} \not\equiv 1\mod{101}$ for any $1 \le i< 100$, use the fact that the multiplicative order (the least number $i$ such that $a^{i} \equiv 1\mod{101}$) will be a divisor of $100$.  This means that $a$ is a generator if and only if $a^{20} \ne 1 \mod{101}$ and $a^{50} \ne 1 \mod{101}$.

Note that $\phi(p-1)$ can be explicitly calculated if a prime factorization for $p-1$ is known.  In general we have $\phi(n) = n\Pi_{q \mid n} (1 - 1/q)$, where $q$ ranges over the prime divisors of $n$.  Here we have $\phi(100) = 100(1-1/2)(1-1/5) = 40$.

The traditional way of computing multiplicative inverses is using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to solve for $83a + 101b = 1$, which will generally be substantially faster than trying every possible inverse.

Comment: So in order to check for example if $2$ is generator, do we do the following?

$$2^{20}=4^{10}=16 \cdot 16 \cdot 16 \cdot 16 \cdot 16=256 \cdot 256 \cdot 16 \equiv 54 \cdot 54 \cdot 16 \equiv 54 \cdot 56=3124 \not\equiv 0 \mod{101} $$

$$2^{50}=32^{10}=625 \cdot 625 \cdot 625=28 \cdot 28 \cdot 25=700 \cdot 28=1960 \not\equiv 0 \mod{101}$$

So, we deduce that $2$ is a generator, right?

Comment: I think some of your arithmetic might be off, eg 54*56 = 3024, and I'm not sure where 625 comes from, but the general approach is valid.  (as a check $a^{50}$ will be $\pm 1$ for any $a$, since it will always square to 1)

Comment: You mean that since we have that $a^{100} \equiv 1 \mod{101} \Leftrightarrow a^{50 \cdot 2} \equiv 1 \mod{101} \Leftrightarrow (a^{50})^2 \equiv 1 \mod{101} \Leftrightarrow a^{50} \equiv \pm 1 \mod{101}$ ? @RolfHoyer

Comment: @evinda that is correct

Comment: We have the following, right?
$$101=1 \cdot 83+18\\83=2 \cdot 18+11\\18=1 \cdot 11+7\\11=1\cdot 7+4\\7=1 \cdot 4+3\\4=1\cdot 3+1 \\3=1\cdot 3+0$$

How can we now find the inverse of $\overline{83}$ at the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$ ?

Comment: go back up the chain, solving for 1.  The calculation starts with $1 = 4-3 = 4 - (7-4) = -7  + 2(11-7) = \ldots$, and ends with something of the form $ 1 = 100a + 83b$, in which case $b$ is your inverse.

Comment: Do you mean $1=101a+83b$? If so, then I found that $1=28 \cdot 83-23 \cdot 101$. So does this mean that $28$ is the inverse of $\overline{83}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{101}^{\star}$ ?

Comment: And then do we solve the equation $\overline{83}x=\overline{10}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\star}$ as follows?
$$$$

$$83x \equiv 10 \mod{101} \Rightarrow 28 \cdot 83 x \equiv 28 \cdot 10 \mod{101} \Rightarrow x \equiv 280 \mod{101} \equiv 78 \mod{101}$$


Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, with $p$ prime, for *any* $a$ we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ by Fermat's little theorem.  But it is possible for some values $a$ to not be generators, if $a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ with $q < p-1$.  For example, in mod $7$, $3$ is a generator, but $2$ is not since $2^3 = 8 \equiv 1$. So the answer to  "or am I wrong" is yes, you am wrong.

Secondly, $\phi(p-1)$ *is* the exact number of generators; for that purpose, the interesting lower bound is irrelevant.  It is as easy to find  $\phi(p-1)$ as it is to factor $(p-1)$.  In general that is not easy, but for the case $p=101$ it is easy. $$100 = 2^2 \cdot 5^2\\\phi(100) = 100 \left( 1 - \frac12 \right) \left( 1 - \frac15 \right) = 40$$ 
So there are 40 generators.

If we find one generator $g$, then any number $g^n$ will also be a generator if $n$ is relatively prime to $100$. So if we find one generator, it  will be easy to find 5 generators.

Comment: So in order to check for example if $2$ is generator, do we do the following?

$$2^{20}=4^{10}=16 \cdot 16 \cdot 16 \cdot 16 \cdot 16=256 \cdot 256 \cdot 16 \equiv 54 \cdot 54 \cdot 16 \equiv 54 \cdot 56=3124 \not\equiv 0 \mod{101} $$

$$2^{50}=32^{10}=625 \cdot 625 \cdot 625=28 \cdot 28 \cdot 25=700 \cdot 28=1960 \not\equiv 0 \mod{101}$$

So, we deduce that $2$ is a generator, right?

Comment: $2$ is a generator. So can we say without proving that $2^3, 2^7, 2^9, 2^{11}, 2^{13}$ are also generators?